# How to make sure that an external USB drive gets the same drive letter?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, hard-drive

Is there a way to reserve a drive letter for an external hard drive?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your USB drive to have the same drive letter on one computer every time you unplug and replug it in or the same drive letter across multiple computers? Furthermore, what OS are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about Windows, I don't think you can permanently assign a drive letter to a particular USB device without third party applications - I find letter assignments sometimes stick for a while but soon revert.

You can assign a drive to appear as a directory in an existing filesystem instead of (or as well as) appearing as a drive letter, and these settings do seem to stick between sessions. For instance the USB drive sat next to my keyboard always appears as c:\mnt\xfer2g

Answer (score 5):

Daniel Petri has a [good write up on this topic](http://www.petri.co.il/control-usb-drive-letter-assignment-in-windows.htm), including a link to a freeware utility called [USBDLM](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) which solves this problem.